# output stream is saving only half of 16 bits

Tags: java, save, outputstream, 16-bit

This is what I've got:

```
 Main:
 buff.clearColor((short)0x00ffff00);

 - - - - - -

 Buffer:
 DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(out);
 for (int i : colorBuffer) {
 dataOutputStream.writeShort(i);
 }

void clearColor(short c)
{
    for(int i=0; i<width*height; i++)
    {
        colorBuffer [i] = c;
    }
}
```

And in file is saved only half of 0x00ffff00,
this one: ff00

...
ff00 ff00 ff00 ff00 ff00 ff00 ff00
ff00 ff00 ff00 ff00 ff00 ff00 ff00 
...

Comment: `0xff00` is not half of 16 bits, it _is_ 16 bits.

Comment: Voted to close this question.  It is a red herring, and will only confuse future visitors to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writeShort(i)` writes a short *right?*

And a `short` is only *2 bytes....* and you need 4, *dont you?*

actually `(short)0x00ffff00` already cuts it. Use `int` e.g.

Comment: You are right, I tried to save it as int but I used
dataOutputStream.write(i); instead of dataOutputStream.writeInt(i);

Comment: So you use buff.clearColor((int)0x00ffff00); and dataOutputStream.writeInt(i); and it still doesnt work?

Comment: `write(i)` only writes the bottom byte of `i`.